# Powershell T-SQL Update Statement Error in Function

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to build  function that extracts information about SQL Server Instance and updates a table with the information:

```
Import-Module "sqlps" -DisableNameChecking
. "D:\V1\CMS\Get-SQLInstance.ps1"

$serverName = 'VIRTSQL120S'
$tableName = 'SQL_SERVER_PRD'

function Update-Table ($srv, $tableName) {
    $get_sql_info = Get-SQLInstance -Computername $serverName

    foreach ($serverinstance in $get_sql_info) {
            $connectionstring=$serverinstance.FullName
            $instance=$serverinstance.SQLInstance
            $version=$serverinstance.Version
            $edition=$serverinstance.edition
            $caption=$serverinstance.Caption
            $port=$serverinstance.Instance_Port

            Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'VIRTSQL152S' -Database 'SQL_info' -Query "
                UPDATE $tableName SET instance = '$instance',
                connection_name = '$connectionstring',
                version = '$version',
                edition = '$edition',
                caption = '$caption',
                port = '$port'
                WHERE servername = '$serverName';"
    }
}

Update-Table $serverName, $tableName`
```

The error that I'm getting is:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.
>   At line:19 char:13
>   +             Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'VIRTSQL152S' -Database >'SQL_info' -Qu ...
>   +             >~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], >SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : >SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

If I execute this outside the function it works with no issues. Any help?

Thanks.

I've tried with a query variable and the error is the same:

> $query = "UPDATE $tableName SET instance = '$instance',`
>                  connection_name = '$connectionstring',`
>                  version = '$version',`
>                 edition = '$edition',`
>                  caption = '$caption',`
>                  port = '$port'`
>                  WHERE servername = '$serverName';"

Comment: I recommend to create a variable and put the update statement in the variable, then use the variable in the  Invoke-Sqlcmd. Please read about multiple lines commands as well (hint: use ` at the end of the line).

Comment: I've try with a query variable and the error is the same. I've edit the question to show the query variable.

Comment: `Write-Host $query` _before_ executing. You should then be able to see the _actual_ query that's failing.

Comment: Instead of using back quotes (always error prone), prefer a "here string" for defining your query. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @gvee thanks for that, rookie mistake, the table name was not being parse because of the coma on the function call.